# TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null In React Table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks, js-scrollintoview

```
const modal =({messages})=>{
    
   const messagesEnd = React.useRef(null);

   const scrollToBottom = () => {
        
        messagesEnd.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    };
  
   useEffect(() => {
          
          scrollToBottom();
        
    }, []); 
    
    const messagesComp = (single_message)=>{
        <TableRow>
        <div>
        <p>{single_message}</p>
        </div>
        </TableRow>
    }
    return (
       
        <div>
        <Table>
        <TableBody>
        {messages ? messages.map(item, index => {
            if(messages.length === index+1){
               return  <div ref={messagesEnd}>messagesComp(item)</div>    
            }else{
                messagesComp(item)
            }
        }
        ) : null}
        </TableBody>
        </Table>
        </div>
            
    );
}
```

I've made an application where if you click on a button a modal pops up and on that modal there are comments which are in form of table rows, as the comments increase the user has to scroll all the to down and I want it to scroll automatically as the modal component mounts. I've used material-ui.
I tried it by ref and also tried others code available here but still it's showing me this error.

Comment: You need to show more code. What is `messagesEnd`? Why do you think there is a property called `current` on that object?

Comment: Provide us more code

Comment: @FábioBCSouza I've added the code, now please check it.its also showing that div in tr is not allowed so i've done alot of work and now i cant replace those divs is there any alternative for that so that i dont have write thousand lines of code again?

Comment: @JeremyHarris i saw that "current" in someones elses code but there error is same even when i removed the current.

Comment: Check is the props messages comes with any value. Put a console.log and if it return at least 1 null so you have just do add a if condition to only set stuff if not null.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your render has two distinct paths, but only one of them sets the element reference:

```js
if(messages.length === index+1){
    return  <div ref={messagesEnd}>messagesComp(item)</div>    
} else {
    messagesComp(item)
}
```

There is even a third path where messages is empty and you would also not get a reference set.

Without the reference, when `useEffect` is called (which will occur regardless of which way you rendered it), it will not have a reference stored in `messagesEnd.current`.

To deal with this, you need to either always have the element reference in your render, which does not seem to be the effect you want, or to check validity before using the ref:

```js
const scrollToBottom = () => {
    if (messagesEnd && messagesEnd.current) {
        messagesEnd.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
};
```